# Making a list comprehension, beginner

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I'm new to Python and am trying to understand list comprehensions so I can use it in my code.

```
pricelist = {"jacket":15, "pants":10, "cap":5, "baseball":3, "gum":1}

products_sold = []

while True:
    product_name = input("what is the name of the product")
    product = {}
    customer_name = input("what is the name of the customer")
    #customer is shopping
    product[sell_price] = pricelist[product_name]
    product["quantity"] = input("how many items were sold?")
    #append the product to a dict

    products_sold.append(product)
```

now I want to have a dict of the entire transaction that should look like this:

```
transaction = {"customer_name":"name",
               "sold":{"jacket":3, "pants":2},
               "bought":{"cap":4, "baseball":2, "gum":"10"}}
```

how would I create a dict, and assign it keys and values with a list comprehension?  I've looked at examples, and I understand them, but I can't figure out how to apply them to my code.

My intentions is to turn my list of products into a list of dicts(transaction) which contain the same information in a different way.

Comment: Is `product` a dict? Does `products_sold` end up being a list of dicts each of which has 1 entry in it?

Comment: Your question needs some clarification. Do you mean that you want to run through your loop a few times and once you are done, create your transaction dictionary from the content of `customer_name`, `product`, and `products_sold` (I assume you also have a `products_bought`, right?). Also, it seems that you are confusing `dict` and `list`. You append to a `list`, i.e. `[].append()`.

Comment: Where do `quantity_sold` and `"Jenny"` come from?

Comment: This question is unanswerable in its current form. If you can rewrite your example code so it works, or properly conveys your intent, you'll probably get a great answer. Until then, I'm voting to close.

Comment: You should add an example of what `products_sold` looks like at the point immediately before you want to try to translate it into the `transaction` dict.

Comment: Is your question actually about how to create a dictionary using dict comprehension?

Answer (score 2):

I'll answer what I think your real problem which is that you want to understand list comprehensions.  IMO, the example that you posted to try to learn list comprehensions is not a good example.  Here's a very trivial example I like to use since it should be easy to relate this to what you already know from another language.

```
# start with a list of numbers
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]   

# create an empty list to hold the new numbers
numbers_times_two = []

# iterate over the list and append the new list the number times two
for number in numbers:
    numbers_times_two.append(number * 2)
```

Hopefully, the above code makes sense and is familiar to you.  Here's the exact same thing using list comprehensions.  Notice, all the same parts are there, just moved around a bit.

```
numbers_times_two = [number * 2 for number in numbers]
```

List comprehensions use square brackets just like a list and it creates a new list from iterating over an iterable (list-like thing) which is numbers in this example.

So, you can see that when you asked a question about using list comprehension to populate a dict, it really doesn't make sense in the context of learning the mechanics of list comprehensions.

Hope this helps.